# Query SQL Server 2008 From Excel 2010

Tags: sql-server, excel

We've got some users who would like to query one of our SQL Server 2008 databases from within Excel 2010. I can see how to retrieve values from a SQL table or view from within Excel, but I cannot see how to pass SQL Server a specific query.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's annoyingly not obvious but you have to choose the data tab then "from other sources" and then choose "From Microsoft query" this then allows you to build and edit a query just like the old days.

Shame on Microsoft for not updating this area with a great query generation tool. Would have been a good reason to upgrade.